# .htaccess not working on href link

Tags: php, .htaccess

please can someone help?
I have the following configuration in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have this for rewriting the url

```
RewriteRule ^user([^/]*)\.php$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Then, i use the following link:

```
<a href="user/<?php echo $rows['user_id'];?>">users</a>.
```

I want to be able to click on link and get user displayed in this url: https:www.mywebsit.com/user/2

But, it shows file not found when i click the link.

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Your rewrite rule is looking for an extension of .php.

Comment: there is no `.php` in the link either add it if you want it or remove it from the rule

Comment: the href link through which i am trying to use is <a href = "user/<?php srows['id'] ?>">users</a>

Comment: I believe problem is in `/user.php?var=$1` in user rule, as you hint you want to pass it as query parameter, but actually you wish to use clean urls /user/{id}. as is link shall work as `/user.php?var={id}`

Comment: I have tried this /user.php?var={id} but still getting the same error

Comment: Now it works using this /user.php?var={id}, i have forgotten the beginning slash. it works but doesn't load database content.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule `^user([^/]*)\.php$` is faulty for `users/id`.

Let's break it into three parts:

`^user`  This is correct so far, you want to match a user prefix.

`([^/]*)`  This is OK but this will fail because it's not expecting a slash after user.  This regex means you want to capture all characters that aren't a slash.

`\.php$`  This is incorrect.  This expects a suffix of .php, but you don't want a .php link.

A corrected version would be: `^user/([^/]*)$`.  Note that I added a slash after user and removed the .php before the end.

Comment: Do you mean this: ^/?user/([0-9]+)$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L] ? Devon

Comment: I mean, ^user/([^/]*)$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L]  this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule is incorrect.

Here's the right one:

```
RewriteRule ^/?user/([0-9]+)$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Comment: While this may work, not explaining your answer is a bad practice.  We also are not sure at this point if user_id is always numeric.

Comment: Thanks kerkouch. Now, is the following correct <a href = "/user.php?var={id}"></a> based on RewriteRule ^/?user/([0-9]+)$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L]

Comment: The url should look like this `https:www.mywebsit.com/user/2`

Comment: Ok this worked; RewriteRule ^/?user/([0-9]+)$ /folderA/folderB/user.php?var=$1 [L] Thank y'all a lot